Sync OneDrive and MS Account File with nautilus
I have a question. In Ubuntu online accounts I added my google and MS accounts, with google I have my google drive File access in nautilus I can access it directly. but with MS there is only the mail option, there is no file option.
I would like to know why, and what can I do to be able to get file access from my MS Account in nautilus.
Hope you can guide me
Have a good day.

That would be a question to ask of Microsoft. Only they would know why there is no file option.

Does this omgubuntu article answer your question?


I would like to know why, and what can I do to be able to get file access from my MS Account in nautilus.

Disclosure: I am the developer of the OneDrive Client for Linux - https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive
There are 5 reliable ways to access OneDrive on Linux/Unix platforms:

Via the OneDrive Client for Linux - https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive - this 'syncs' your data, bi-directional operation, open source and free. Supports Personal, Business & SharePoint account types and Shared Folders. Client Side Filtering is a major feature so you only sync what you need. A Docker container is also available for all major architectures (i686, x86_64, ARMHF, AARCH64). If you need a GUI for onedrive client management use: https://github.com/bpozdena/OneDriveGUI
Via the 'onedriver' client - https://github.com/jstaf/onedriver - Native file system that only provides the OneDrive 'on-demand' functionality, open source and free. Supports Personal, Business account types. Currently does not support Shared Folders or SharePoint.
Via 'rclone' - https://rclone.org/ - one way sync client, open source and free. Has limitations with SharePoint.
Via non-free clients such as 'insync', 'ExpanDrive'
Via the web browser of your choice

Additionally, whilst in Ubuntu 24.x GNOME46 also includes a capability to access Microsoft OneDrive, it does not provide anywhere near the capabilities of the first three options.

I installed OneDrive Client for Linux but I don't quite get it, with google drive I only have to save a new file in the directory or just edit an existing one and that's all, but with OneDrive Client for Linux I have to sync the changes manually every time? I saw an option of a background process to sync it for me but seems resource consumption, did I get it wrong?
